# Working further on idea from patent for student project and publishing

Tags: publications, patents

I have simulated and aerodynamic concept from a patent based on aerodynamics for reducing Drag. Can I publish my paper ?

What is general trend ? **Most patents on Aerodynamics concepts are just ideas or first they obtain promising result experimentally or numerically, then they publish patent.**

Answer (score 3):

Writing a paper solo is hard. Not only do you need to do all the experimental work yourself (in this case, simulating aerodynamics), but you also need to be on top of the relevant existing literature.

You need the latter, so that when you come to write up, you know **what** gets written up, **how** it gets written up, and **when** and **where** it gets written up.

Without that, you won't be able to write a paper that would get accepted by any reputable journal.

To find precedents in the literature for a particular patent, take the names of the holders of the patent, and then search for them as author names in the usual literature databases for your subject.

There are specific literature databases that will give you false negatives, but few false positives: that is, they will find much but not all of the good relevant literature, with relatively little junk literature, e.g. [sciencedirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/). Then there are general literature databases, that are much more inclusive, which means you're less likely to miss important papers, but they'll be buried amid a lot of junk results - e.g. [google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/).

As to your specific question: filing a patent is usually (depending on the country) time-consuming and expensive. Which means that patent-filers will either have done their due diligence on novelty and validity, including experimental and numerical analysis; or they've got sufficient money (or are so unaverse to risk) that they can file the patent application first (perhaps to establish precedence, or just out of vanity), and then do the work later.